# Changing Background Color of Windows Phone 8 Application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to change the background color of my Windows Phone application pages using the following code

```
(App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Colors.Red;    //For Changing the Accent Color
(App.Current.Resources["PhoneBackgroundBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Colors.White; //For Changing the Backgroung Color
```

The Accent color of the application is getting changed successfully, but my app background color is not getting changed. Please helm me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In App.xaml.cs, in the method InitializePhoneApplication, try changing the RootFrame object Background Property to the color you want.

Comment: Thanks @MakanWG, it worked. In the similar way how can I change the font color??